# Is it possible to integrate Cardano in Unreal Engine?

Tags: wallet, integration, gaming, plugin

I want to build a game using `Unreal` and I want to use Cardano's wallets for authentication.

Is it possible to integrate `Unreal Engine` with Cardano's network via a plugin or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a Google search and found a couple of projects that may be of interest to you:

https://devpost.com/software/unreal-engine-cardano-plugin
"Unreal Engine 5 plugin that allows users to connect to the Cardano API via Blockfrost.io"

https://www.lidonation.com/en/proposals/cardanosharp-unrealengine-sdk
"a plugin that will give UnrealEngine developers the ability to mint Tokens and NFTs in a way that integrates with their game logic"